# How can i define a job in gitlab-ci.yaml which gets triggerd when deleting an environment?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a gitlab-ci.yaml file which creates an environment. Within the environment i defined an `on_stop`-action which will be triggered as soon as i manually stop the environment in the GitLab User Interface.

My config looks similar to this:

```
stop_review_app:
  when: manual
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    on_stop: stop

stop:
  extends: .delete
  stage: stop
  script:
    - kubectl scale -n $NAMESPACE deployment app-name --replicas=0
```

Basically everything works fine. Now i want to run a different script if i actually delete my environment in the Gitlab UI. So i was looking for an option named `on_delete` which works the same way as `on_stop` does. But it doesn't exist. Shouldn't something exist like that? How can i achive my requirements using gitlab-ci.yaml?

I'm running GitLab Community Edition 15.2.2

Comment: That's Not possible using your YAML scripts. `on_stop` runs the instructions/event in GitLab Runner but the feature you are looking for (Delete environment automatically when you delete env on UI) is running outside the runner.

Comment: But as a workaround, you can write a small pipeline and schedule it like every 5 mins. and that pipeline should delete the marked environment.